# How to close client connection when Nginx's upstream server close conncetion?

Tags: nginx, tcp

(1) I have an http server， listen port 8080, which sleep 5 second when handle GET request:

```
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write("Hello World !")
    time.sleep(5)
    print 'after sleep'
    return
try:
    server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), myHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.socket.close()
```

(2) I have a nginx, listen 1014 and forward request to 8080,

```
upstream kubeapiserver {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    keepalive 30;
}
server {
    listen       1014;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://kubeapiserver;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1800s;
        proxy_read_timeout 1800s;
        proxy_send_timeout 1800s;
    }
}
```

(3) make a long request to 1014

```
import time
url="http://127.0.0.1:1014"
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url)
print r.headers
print r.status_code
print r.content
while True:
    time.sleep(10)
```

AND I FOUND with `netstat -nap | egrep "(8080)|(1014)"` that:
when the B connection close, the A connection **STILL ESTABLISHED**

How to close client connection when Nginx's upstream server close conncetion ? How to config?

Comment: which is A and B in your case? You've numbered your cases  as 1) 2) and 3) in your question